# Split order items and reconcile them later with Spring Kafka -Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an order which consists of items. My producer splits the order into items to send each item to a specific topic based on an item attribute.

There is a consumer behind each topic which processes the items and sends them to a particular "reconcile" topic. Some items may not be processed, so they will never be sent back into the "reconcile" topic.

I'd like to write a consumer with Spring Kafka that listen to the "reconcile" topic and reconstruct the specific order by adding his items. If some items are not not available in "reconcile" topic, the consumer has to construct a partial order after some time with items related to that specific orders.   Any reference implementation will be helpful

Comment: Hi. Your question is not specific to Confluent Platform, and Spring-Kafka is not the same as Spring Cloud Streams Binders. Please dont readd the tags